# Converting markdown to html with Pagedown, markup lost

Tags: javascript, jquery, markdown, pagedown

I have a message function sent from server that I want to output on a web page. Message is written in markdown code, and I want to output it as html using Pagedown converter. The conversion seems to be working, as I can get correct html-tags when I output the message in the console. The problem is that when I try to send it back to the html element where I want to display it, the markup is gone and replaced by p-tags. See simplified code below. I have never used markdown or Pagedown before, have I missed something?

Html:

```
<span class="Markdown">**I am bold**</span>
```

Javascript:

```
var message = $('.Markdown').text();
var converter = new Markdown.Converter();
var output = converter.makeHtml(message);
console.log(output);      // Outputs "<strong>I am bold</strong>"
$('.Markdown').html(output);    // Outputs "<p>I am bold</p>"
```

Comment: OK, is there a way to output "<strong>I am bold</strong>" instead of "<p>I am bold</p>"?

Comment: is Sanitizer what do you need? (http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown)

Comment: No, the result is the same with Sanitizer.

Comment: Can anyone explain why the strong-tag is being removed? How can this be the normal behaviour?

Comment: Seems to be working fine in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CV47f/ There must be something else you are doing.